# Local User Account Disappeared After Domain Upgrade

Tags: active-directory, domain, users, local

I upgraded to server 2012 r2 from 2008 r2
I have all computers in AD
The workstations with local logons are losing the local user that i have set up on them... (the admin logon is not disappearing)

These workstations are student computers and do not need to be joined to the domain but i need to manage them in Group Policy

Comment: `These workstations are student computers and do not need to be joined to the domain but i need to manage them in Group Policy` - I'm not understanding how the two things are related. You don't manage domain based Group Policy for domain joined computers or domain users with local user accounts.

Comment: When you say the computers are "losing" the local user, what do you mean by that?  Are you saying that the user no longer exists in computer management?

Comment: I understand all computers are joined to domain but students still logon with local users. You manage computers using Domain Group Policy. Correct? Have you checked on computer manager if local users are still exists? Are they enabled? All workstations the same way?